# Can I change the meaning of operators? For example ∈ as MemberQ

Tags: evaluation, customization

I spotted this under `\[Element]` in the Wolfram documentation: "`x ∈ y` is by default interpreted as `Element[x, y]`."

By default? So can it be changed? I'd like to be able to use ∈ and ∉ (`\[NotElement]`) as shorthand to check list membership. Even better, can I have ∈ mean `MemberQ` or `Element` depending on whether it's used on a `List` expression? Ideally I'd like it by default in every notebook.

Comment: You might find more success in defining a similarly looking undefined operator to do such a thing. I’m not sure I would advise making the change to a defined operator as you desire, but it is possible.

Comment: I suggest using one the similar-looking Unicode characters, such as ⋹, ∊, ⋳, ⋿, ⋲ ...

Comment: A lot of the calculus and region functionality rest on the already built-in evaluation rules for `Element[]`, so don't be surprised if they break because of what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default? So can it be changed?

No, it cannot be changed. I believe the description is incorrect.

Some of the existing answers change the meaning of the `Element` function, not the interpretation of the `\[Element]` operator. That is not the same thing. Also, it will almost certainly break things very badly.

[Michael's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261071/12) is the only one which actually changes the interpretation of `\[Element]`, but only within notebooks, i.e. only in StandardForm. This is all that the notation package can do. It won't change the interpretation in `InputForm`, i.e. the plain text interpretation that applies when using `Get`. I believe that is hard-wired into the parser.

The only reasonable answer here is that no, it is not possible to change the interpretation of `\[Element]`. If you try, you will likely seriously break things. Don't do this. If you really want an operator for `MemberQ`, use one of the operators without built-in meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Although you can do it, I would advice against it because you may upset something unexpected.

Anyway to do this you may first unprotect the command, clear possible definitions and redefine it. Finally you protect it again.

If you want this as default, you put it in the "init.m" file (look it up in the help)

Here is the code:

```
Unprotect[Element, NotElement];
ClearAll[Element, NotElement];
Element[x_?AtomQ, y_] := MemberQ[y, x];
NotElement[x_, y_] := ! MemberQ[y, x];
Element[x_List, y_] := AllTrue[x, MemberQ[y, #] &];
NotElement[x_List, y_] := NoneTrue[x, MemberQ[y, #] &];
Protect[Element, NotElement];
```

To test the MemberQ functionality:

```
1 ∈ {1, 2}
1 ∉ {1, 2}
True
False
```

And the MemberQ functionality:

```
{1, 2} ∈ {1, 2, 3}
{4, 5} ∉ {1, 2, 3}
True
True
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Notation package to make the input `x ∈ y` be interpreted as `MemberQ[x, y]`.  Besides being a literal interpretation of the question in the OP, this way does not override `Element` or `MemberQ`, only input syntax and optionally output-formatting.

Load the package with `Get` or `Needs`:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

Pick the input form from the Notation palette and enter:

[image]

One can use the input-output form to have `MemberQ` displayed as `\[Element]` if desired; however, you cannot stop `MemberQ` from evaluating to `True` or `False` except by holding it:

[image]

Note `ToExpression["x\[Element]{1,2,3}", StandardForm]` is converted to `MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x]`, but I doubt that will cause trouble for  built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

I give you a version that is only used when MemberQ returns True or False.

```
Element[form_,lst_List]:=With[{result=MemberQ[lst,form]},
  result/;Or[result,Not@result]
];
```

Then

```
Element[3,{1,2,3,4,5}]
(* True *)
```

Using Block you can do things that are otherwise not possible such as this:

```
Unprotect[SetPrecision];
$ModifySetPrecision=True;

SetPrecision[x_Real,p_Real?Positive]/;$ModifySetPrecision:=
  Block[{$ModifySetPrecision=False},SetPrecision[x,p+15]];

SetPrecision[x_Real,p_Integer?Positive]/;$ModifySetPrecision:=
  Block[{$ModifySetPrecision=False},SetPrecision[x,p+15]];
```

Then

```
x=SetPrecision[2.2`17,20];
Precision[x]
```

(* 35. *)

My changes above will certainly slow down the affected functions, and it is conceivable this code will not work in a future version of Wolfram Language. It is conceivable you have another use for $ModifySetPrecision. Other than that, what unexpected changes could it have?